# Bigraph Model checker instalation error Makefile command problem

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I wanted to install the model checker BigMC tool (https://github.com/AlessandroCaste/bigmc) but I have these errors:

[image]

Comment: Please cut and paste errors into your question, properly formatted, rather than adding a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language construction is only available since C++11 standard and it seems that your code compiles with an older standard. The root cause is that the author was not explicit about the C++ standard he uses, but the default has changed from C++98 to C++14 in [GCC6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html#cxx). The author has been using the newer GCC, while your system seems to have an older version.

You can try to compile the software by passing additional flags at the `configure` step, i.e. `./configure CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11`.

BTW. For future please try to copy and paste your error as text, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Images are not readable, searchable nor allow to copy text fragments.